# How to check if a slice is inside a slice in GO?

Tags: list, go

I  have the following code:

```
func main(){
    l1 := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    l2 := []string {"a", "c"}
    //l2 in l1?
}
```

I can check this using loops and flags but Is there a simple way to check if l2 is inside l1 like python command "l2 in l1"?

Comment: Yes, you need to loop -- `l2 in l1` is just hiding the loops from you.

Comment: How do define `in`? same order? order doesn't matter?

Comment: Order doesn't matter in this case

Comment: If order does not matter then it is a problem of set containing another set.

Comment: If order doesn't matter, it's not the same as Python's `in`, because `['a', 'c'] in ['a', 'b', 'c']` is `False`

Comment: Can you provide some examples or Python code that clarifies your question? What if `l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]` and `2 = ["a","a","c"]` does is l1 still contain in l2?

Comment: I haven't looked but isn't there some stuff with reflect and unsafe that would just let you look at the slice pointer and see if it's off the same array? I mean, when I read the question title here, that's what I think of, although the rest of the question seems to be set intersection.

Comment: @ZanLynx: you don't need unsafe, you get the array address via `&a[0]`.

Comment: @JimB: That won't tell you if it is pointing into the same backing array if someone made a slice with a new start index.

Comment: @ZanLynx, it’s the same address that’s stored in the slice header. You can check if the address is between the start address and last address if you want to know if they have overlapping arrays (which may or may not be more clear using the unsafe package, I’d type it out both ways to see)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following from [How to check if a slice is inside a slice in GO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549979/how-to-check-if-a-slice-is-inside-a-slice-in-go?noredirect=1#comment84096020_48549979), @Mostafa posted the following for checking if an element is in a slice:

```
func contains(s []string, e string) bool {
   for _, a := range s {
        if a == e {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Now it's a matter of checking element by element:

```
func subslice (s1 []string, s2 []string) bool {
    if len(s1) > len(s2) { return false }
    for _, e := range s1 {
        if ! contains(s2,e) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Of course, this ignores duplicates, so there's room for improvement.

Answer (score 5):

@Kabanus's answer is of O(mn) time complexity. Despite being slow in large scale, it only requires elemenent of both set to be `==` comparable, which is almost any cases.

But if your data is hashable, and preferably hashable by default (i.e. can be used as key of a `map`), using an auxiliary map is a much more efficient way:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Universe map[string]bool

func NewUniverse(s []string) Universe {
    u:=make(Universe)
    for _,i:=range s {
        u[i]=true
    }
    return u
}

func (u Universe) CountainSet(s []string) bool {
    for _,i:=range s {
        if !u[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(NewUniverse([]string{"a","b","c"}).CountainSet([]string{"a","c"}))
}
```

Dealing with duplicate is very trivial: change map[string]bool to map[string]int and compare element count.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/pdM4DO3UO2e

Comment: Please add time and memory complexity of your algorithm for comparison.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you are looking for set issubset:

In Python it would look like this:

```
In [1]: l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]

In [2]: l2 = ["a", "c"]

In [3]: set(l2).issubset(l1)
Out[3]: True
```

The most similar version of this in go uses [golang-set](https://github.com/deckarep/golang-set) and looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/deckarep/golang-set"
)

func sliceToSet(mySlice []string) mapset.Set {
    mySet := mapset.NewSet()
    for _, ele := range mySlice {
        mySet.Add(ele)
    }   
    return mySet
}

func main() {

    l1 := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    l2 := []string{"a", "c"}

    s1 := sliceToSet(l1)
    s2 := sliceToSet(l2)

    result := s2.IsSubset(s1)

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

The time complexity of above approach is linear time. The time complexity of issubset itself is O(n), where n is length of a set we are checking if subset, in this case `s2`. There is also conversion from slice to set that is also linear time.